# Would using external perl in Coco application be considered bad practice?

Tags: macos, cocoa, perl

I have some perl applications & modules that I use for a number of tasks.

I would like to bundle these up and place a Coca wrapper around them, so I can distribute them to other people.

Assuming I can force use of the bundled OSX perl and include the modules I need inside my application, is there any real problems with doing this?  I really do not want to re-implement everything I have already done.

Comment: As long as you manage the dependencies and provide a decent installer / documentation, quite OK.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with using the system-provided tools, include Perl. Things to consider:

- The version of Perl changes from release to release. So if you need to support 10.4-10.7, you wind up with very diverse versions of Perl to support.
- It can be tricky to include your own versions of modules, particularly if those modules rely on other modules, and most especially if those modules include compiled code.
- Occasionally users mess with their system Perl more than you would like. In particular, they might install new modules or upgrade existing modules. Ideally you can say "don't do that," but it can create problems.

My team has had nightmares dealing with `Net::SSL` on different versions of OS X. We finally have removed Perl entirely from our code base due to the headaches of managing all the different versions of Perl and of Perl modules that might be in the system libraries.

But if you keep your dependencies simple, then there's no problem using the system Perl.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you employ good coding practices, it should be fine. I've never use Perl in a Cocoa application myself. You might want to check out Camel Bones: http://sourceforge.net/projects/camelbones/ 
Its a Perl/Cocoa bridge. Never used it myself, but it may help.